# Is my external hard drive dead?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, hard-drive

I have an external 500GB HDD. It has Mini-B USB port and tonight I bought a new cable for it. Now, I'm testing the cable (and the hard drive). When I plug it into my pc, the HDD's light turns on but my Xubuntu doens't recognize it.

There is no "sdb" in the "/dev" directory. I checked it by Gparted, testdisk, fdisk, ... but none of them could find the device to check it. I even checked the "dmesg" but there was no sign of my HDD.

How can I understand if the hard drive is dead or just the cable is broken?
(Totally how can I get if the HDD (or any other devices like coolpads, ...) is identified by linux?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking for the hard disk in "Disk" section. If not then I would recommend using Trinity Rescue Kit Available [here](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=DOWNLOADING_TRK_3.4_BUILD_372_FROM_OSU_OPEN_SOURCE_LABS_&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en)!

or follow link

http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=DOWNLOADING_TRK_3.4_BUILD_372_FROM_OSU_OPEN_SOURCE_LABS_&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en

If still problem persists Try changing the cables ( buy after testing the cable first ) 
if none of the above works then probably you should consider that it is dead. Lastly try it with a Windows PC as Well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try another USB Cable?
Try finding the Device via the `lsusb` command, this could give you a hint if the Controller is dead, but to be sure, open up your external HDD and connect the HDD inside directly to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

3 things are possible

1. Your replacement cable doesn't have the necessary pinout/cabling for the necessary power draw
2. The external hard drive enclosure's electronics are damaged
3. The hard drive it self is dead

---

Easiest way to know if your data is safe is to open the enclosure and plug the hard drive into another enclosure (if using a laptop) that works or connect it directly to a SATA cable and power cable inside of a PC.